# Host images on imgbb sometimes showing error

Tags: reactjs

I upload images on one of reactjs project and host on imgbb but sometimes posting is working successfully and sometimes showing error.message: "Can't get target upload source info".
What's the problem actually ?

```
 const [coverPhoto, setCoverPhoto] = useState([]);

    const onChangeCover = (data) => {

        setCoverPhoto(data)

        const imgAPIKey = 'c83daa0cd70c09ca51b747864c4a22e1'
        const image = data[0].file
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('image', image)
        const url = `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=${imgAPIKey}`
        fetch(url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData

            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(async result => {
                console.log('imgbbCover', result)
                const coverPhoto = result.data.url
                await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/profiles/${email}`,
                    {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'content-type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({ coverPhoto })
                    })
            })

    }
```

[see the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtdLB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've find a reason not posting the images properly sometimes is actually the freemium version has some limitations, one is not hosting every time properly...
Also tried the Cloudinary free hosting and found the same issue .